# TYPO3 9.5 get "paste as reference" back

Tags: reference, typo3, paste, typo3-9.x

I switched from Typo3 Version 7.6 to Version 9.5 and miss an feature. In 7.6, if you copy an content element and paste it, there is an popup which asks if you want to paste it as copy or reference

[image: Image of the popup in Typo3 7.6]

Is there a way to get this popup back? It seams that this popup is removed/deactivated at Version 8.x. I don't know if this is completely removed or just deactivated as default. I can't find information about this. I hope someone here can tell me I can get this back and if so, what I have to do.

Answer (score 1):

This popup is not part of the TYPO3 core.
It was introduced by `EXT:gridelements`. 
As `Ext:gridelements` needs a deep integration into the core and the core changed much you need to wait some time to get a full working matching extension for the new TYPO3 version.

The new version might be available faster if you support the developer.